# Which area of the screen user look at the most?

Tags: user-experience

Is there a graph or chart or something that indicates which area of the screen attracts user attention first and the most?
Thanks.

Comment: Flagged as off-topic.  Belongs on UX.SE, not hear.

Comment: If you want to put something important, avoid where Users never notice. Is that reason ok?

Comment: Please understand, your topic is valid and is a good one.  Believe it or not, I flagged your question for your benefit.  You can get a good answer on this site, however, the question belongs on the User Experience (UX) site, within the StackExchange network.  I didn't flag your question because it's offensive.  I flagged it so that a mod can move your question to much more appropriate location.  Hope that helps.

Comment: oh, I see, I never noticed that site. I thought Stackoverflow covers everything programmers need to know. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some research regarding how people read web pages:

http://www.nngroup.com/articles/f-shaped-pattern-reading-web-content/